# Как мне сделать мою игру динамической?

Tags: c#, .net, разработка-игр

Я хочу написать простенькую игру, суть которой заключается в том, чтобы я заспаунил игрока и 4 бомбы, и нужно просто управлять этим игроком, чтобы он не попал на бомбу. Если он попал на бомбу то игра заканчивается.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы после того, как я создал поле с игроком и бомбами, я мог управлять этим игроком с помощью кнопок A, W, S, D?

Вот мой код, я написал основное, что запланировал: метод Move() у игрока, само поле и т.д.

```
class Game
{
    static private void StartGame()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите спавн Х игрока");
        int Player_X = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Введите спавн Y игрока");
        int Player_Y = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));

        Console.Clear();

        Bomb[] Bombs = { new Bomb(10, 12), new Bomb(13, 12), new Bomb(15, 10) };

        Field field = new Field(20, 20, Bombs, new Player_CT(Player_X, Player_Y, 'd'), 1, 1);
        field.MakeField();
        while (true)
            field.player.Move();

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartGame();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


class Bomb
{
    int _x;
    int _y;

    public int X { get { return _x; } set { if (value > 0) _x = value; } }
    public int Y { get { return _y; } set { if (value > 0) _y = value; } }

    public Bomb(int X, int Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

}

class Field
{
    int _x;
    int _y;
    int X { get { return _x; } set { if (value >= 0) _y = value; } }
    int Y { get { return _y; } set { if (value >= 0) _y = value; } }
    int Height;
    int Width;

    Bomb[] _bombs;
    Bomb[] Bombs { get { return _bombs; } set { _bombs = value; } }

    public Player player;

    public Field(int Height, int Width, Bomb[] Bombs, Player player, int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        this.Bombs = Bombs;
        this.Height = Height; // Y -- start, Y + Height -- end
        this.Width = Width; // X -- start, X + Width -- end
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void MakeField()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
        for (int i = 1, j = 1; i <= Height; i++)
        {
            if (j > 9)
                j = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(j);
            j++;
        }
        for (int i = 1, j = 1; i <= Width; i++)
        {
            if (j > 9)
                j = 1;
            Console.Write(j);
            j++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Bombs[i].X, Bombs[i].Y);
            Console.Write('B');
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(player.X, player.Y);
        Console.Write('P');
    }
    public void IsOver()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (player.X == Bombs[i].X && player.Y == Bombs[i].Y)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Width + 50, Height + 50);
                Console.WriteLine("You\'ve lost!");
            }
        }
    }
    public void PrintPlayer()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(player.X, player.Y);
        Console.WriteLine('Y');
    }

    public string this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Bombs[i].X == x && Bombs[i].Y == y)
                {
                    return "Bomb";
                }
            }
            if (player.X == x && player.Y == y)
            {
                return "Player";
            }
            else
                return "empty point";
        }
    }

}

class Player_CT : Player
{
    public Player_CT(int x, int y, char d) : base(x, y, d) { }
    bool DefuseKits; // defuse the bomb with defuse kits - 5 seconds, without - 10 seconds
    int _hp = 100;
    int hp { get { return _hp; } set { if (value > -1 && value < 101) _hp = value; } } // hp range = (0, 100)

    public void DefuseBomb(Bomb bomb)
    {
        if (this.X - bomb.X <= 2 && this.Y - bomb.Y <= 2) // находится в двух точках от бомбы
        {
            if (DefuseKits)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                bomb = null; // bomb doesnt exist anymore
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                bomb = null;
            }
        }
    }
    public void TakeDefuseKit(DefuseKit[] defusekits)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < defusekits.Length; i++)
        {
            if (this.X - defusekits[i].X <= 2 && this.Y - defusekits[i].Y <= 2)
            {
                DefuseKits = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

class DefuseKit
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}


class Player
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public char _direct;
    public char direct
    {
        get
        {
            return _direct;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == 'w')
                _direct = 'u';
            else if (value == 'd')
                _direct = 'r';
            else if (value == 'a')
                _direct = 'l';
            else if (value == 's')
                _direct = 'd';
        }
    }  // u - up; d - down; l - left; r - right; WASD - W - up A - left S - down D - right

    public Player(int x, int y, char d)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.direct = d;
    }
    public void Move()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo a = Console.ReadKey();
        direct = a.KeyChar;
        int X1 = this.X;
        int Y1 = this.Y;
        if (direct == 'u')
        {
            this.Y += 1;
        }
        else if (direct == 'd')
        {
            this.Y -= 1;
        }
        else if (direct == 'r')
        {
            this.X += 1;
        }
        else if (direct == 'l')
        {
            this.Y -= 1;
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(X1, Y1);
        Console.Write(' ');
    }
}
```

Comment: Должен быть игровой цикл который будет крутить логику снова и снова

Comment: `Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: У меня почти заработало, но все же работает не всегда правильно, скажите, что неправильного есть в этой логике https://pastebin.com/tLKE6Jfb метода Move() ?

Comment: я отладил, и дело в том, что у меня пишет в консоль букву той клавиши, которую я нажимаю, как это исправить?

Comment: `Console.ReadKey(true);`